# How and what do need to do to use CAN on android?

Tags: android, linux, iso, can-bus, obd-ii

I need to know what software or programs and hardware I need to effectively communicate with CANbus and my usb2can through android phone. Everything I read or try doesn't seem to be legit or doesnt breakdown the in between things that need to be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the Android phone's perspective the usb2can is just a USB device. You would probably need a USB OTG adapter, but other than that, you don't need any special hardware.

For USB programming with Android, here is your primary resource: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice

And it looks like the usb2can has a set of drivers targeting Linux, located here: https://github.com/krumboeck/usb2can

I would start by simply creating a simple Android App to enumerate the USB device and print the device descriptors. After that, the linux drivers should lead the way to doing what you need to do.